# Making the folder unmanaged by SVN

Tags: svn

Is it possible to delete the folder from repository the way it wont be removed from each user's local repository?

In my case there is a directory named 'config' that was intended to be version-controlled. Now we decided to remove that directory from version-control but leave it on each person computer (and add it to svn:ignore by the way). Problem is, if I delete that directory with "svn delete" - it will get deleted from everyone's computer and I don't want that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only way I know of is to keep it on your own working copy:

```
svn delete --keep-local
```

You're stuck because you can't ignore a version controlled file.

If it's *really* important and you use TortoiseSVN, then you could perform the operation in 2 phases - create a client-side pre-update hook to export the directory (or files), then in post-update (after svn:ignore has been added to working copy) copy the directory or files back again.

Sounds like a right PITA though and IMHO you're probably better off sending an email explaining the situation and giving advance notice to export *config* before you do the commit.

Comment: In TortoiseSVN (shell menu in windows file explorer) you have a menu item called **Delete and add to ignore list**. Will this command keep it locally?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add svn:ignore on the directory once it's un-version controlled; but in order to get it out of version control, I think you'll have to svn:delete it, have each dev copy it out,  delete the .svn directories, do an update, then copy it back.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542065/svn-remove-file-from-repository-without-deleting-local-copy) may help also.