# Delete dir/files from SVN remote repo without causing local non-versioned copy to be deleted

Tags: svn

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542065/svn-remove-file-from-repository-without-deleting-local-copy) deals with the question of "un-versioning" local files/directories so you keep them locally but they are removed from the remote repo. I have somewhat the opposite problem - another developer committed some XCode project directories which should be per-user. I can't checkout this dir locally because I already have a local non-versioned. And if I delete them from the repo directly, I'm worried that both of our local copies will be deleted when we update.

To summarise:
 - Developer and I both have a local folder  containing several files
 - Developer committed his  dir to SVN
 - Developer's working copy contains versioned 
 - my working copy contains non-versioned  and won't let me update

What is the best route here under two circumstances:

1. The developer is avaialble to help fix things
2. I have to do everything and try not to break the developer's working copy

Thanks! We are using a SVN 1.6 repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove files remotely without checking out a particular working copy:

```
 $ svn rm -m "Removing user property" http://repo/svn/project/.userprops
```

However, you can always checkout a new working directory elsewhere on your computer and do your removal from there. I recommend this method because it allows you to check and verify what you're doing before committing changes. Plus, you can undo a bad revision by doing a *reverse merge*.

Suppose the revision with these wrongly added per-user files is revision 43210:

```
$ mkdir temp
$ cd temp                # New clean directory for new clean checkout
$ svn co http://repos/svn/project/trunk project-trunk
$ cd project-trunk
$ svn merge -c -43210    # Removes the bad revision
$ svn commit -m"Reversing revision 43210 because of bad pre-user files added"
```

And that's it.

By the way, I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that will prevent this from happening again. You can simply configure it not to allow users to add and commit these per-user files in your project.

Comment: If I remove these files from SVN in a normal way, when I update won't SVN go "ah, you have those deleted files locally, I'll delete them"?

Comment: Only if you didn't make a change in the local file. Then, you can always get it back by doing a `svn cat -rPREV $filename`. If you made a change, you'll get a conflict during the update. It'll say _local edit, incoming delete upon update_. Do a `svn resolved $filename` and then `svn rm --keep-local $filename`.