# Make a normal add out of a svn copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I copied a file in my SVN-aware IDE (Visual Studio with Ankh) and modified it. This did a `svn copy` of the file like it should usually. In this case, however, I wanted to add it normally without connection to the other file.

This is what I did (using TortoiseSVN), which works, but is kind of awkward:

1. `Undo add` the copied file, which deletes the file and puts it in the Recycle Bin
2. Restore the deleted file from the Recycle Bin
3. Re-add the file to SVN

Note: this all happened in the working copy without a commit first.

Is there a better way to do this? (i.e. make a copied staged file into a normal added one)

**Edit:** It seems that `svn rm --keep-local` (followed by `svn add`) might do what I want on the command line (I haven't tried it yet). But I haven't seen the option in TortoiseSVN though. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542100/1467476).

Comment: Why do you want to copy the file without retaining its history?

Comment: @bahrep Because logically it doesn't have anything to do with the other, I just copied it because I wanted less typing (being a lazy programmer ...)